# Getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 when no negative numbers are involved

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception, adjacency-matrix

I've been creating a graph to run my implementation of A* on, and I seem to be stuck at a certain error for finding the neighbours of a node. My logic is that in my 2D ArrayList which represents an adjacency matrix, I have in list 1: Nodes a b c d, and in List 2, Nodes a b c d, and the indexes at which they meet should have a value other than 0 in them to show that an edge exists. This is what I'm trying to do here:

```
public List<Node> neighbours(Node a){
        List<Node> neighbours = new ArrayList<Node>();
        for(int i = 0; i < nodes.size() - 1; i ++){
            int n = matrix.get(matrix.indexOf(a)).get(i);
            if (n != 0){
                neighbours.add(nodes.get(i));
            }
        }
        return neighbours;
    }
```

However I get a nice `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` error, I've stared at this for 30 minutes but I have no clue where this -1 is coming from. I will also add the code for the construction of the matrix as this may hold a clue:

```
public void addNode (Node a){
        int count = 0;
        nodes.add(a);
        matrix.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(nodes.size()));
        for (List<Integer> list : matrix){
            count++;
            int diff = Math.abs(nodes.size() - list.size());
            if (diff != 0){
                for (int i = 0; i < diff; i ++)
                    matrix.get(count-1).add(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

I update the size of the matrix each time a node is added.
I hope this isn't a case where the answer is just staring me in the face but I'm too tired to see it. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure, that value a is in matrix? If no then

```
matrix.indexOf(a)
```

may return -1 when this value is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You've already coded the -1 in:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < nodes.size() - 1; i ++){
```

It is pretty sure the cause of the exception, So `nodes` is created but it has no elements in it (zero as size minus one returns -1). But without the full running example it's hard to say. It's not a problem of the code but of the sample data. Please include a fully running code.

Comment: It's quite long so I don't want to bother people but thank you for this answer I will look into that.

Comment: This is a misleading answer. The -1 is not from the condition. In such case the loop wont be executed. The actual explanation is on Szymon's answer.